# save NSManagedContext in some cases only

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I need to implement cancel/save behavior for the `Core Data` objects. I have a `UITableView` for which I got data from `NSFetchedResultsController`.

```
- (void) configureWithCategoryItem: (CategoryItem *) categoryItem
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[CategoryItem entityName]];

    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryId = %@", categoryItem.categoryId];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:[CategoryItem defaultContext]
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"title"
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch: NULL];
    self.layers = [self categoryLayers];
    self.sectionTitle = categoryItem.title;
}
```

Every click on the cell in this table view

```
LayerItem *layerItem = [self.layers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
layerItem.isSelected = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

And in the navigation bar I have two buttons:
**Cancel** - I need to dismiss controller without saving the results to the core data,
**Save** - I need to save results and dismiss controller

The save method now looks like this:

```
- (void) saveChanges
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext;
    if ([localContext hasChanges]) {
        [localContext save: NULL];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kEADatabaseWasUpdated object:nil];
    }
}
```

Is there some instrument in `Core Data` which can help me to implement this behavior?

I tried to use separate `NSManagedObjectContext` and `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` but didn't receive good result.. Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) cancelChanges
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext;
    [localContext rollback];
}
```